# Disabling Edge's IE-compatibility mode for new tabs or specific sites

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iis, tabs, microsoft-edge

I am an administrator working with an application that runs primarily in Internet Explorer. Most features only work in IE or Edge with IE-compatibility mode enabled. However, we have identified some functionality that only works in Edge in non-compatibility mode. The URLs users use to access these pages are consistent and distinct, so if a user directly accesses the URL by entering it, everything works as intended.

So as an example:

webpage.com:8000 works in IE or IE-compatibility mode.
webpage.com:8001 works only in Edge without IE compatibility.

Users typically access webpage.com:8001 by clicking a link on webpage.com:8000. If IE-compatibility mode is enabled on webpage.com:8000, webpage.com:8001 automatically opens in IE-compatibility mode in a new tab. Users can manually exit the mode, or simply click the address bar and hit enter, but this is not an ideal solution for UX.

I have tried to modify redirect settings in IIS in the hopes that it would force a new window to open and evaluate the browser's IE-compatibility site list rather than inherit the setting of the previous tab. This did not change the behavior. I also searched for settings in Edge that would force all links to open in new windows and did not find anything appropriate.

Comment: How did you manage IE mode in your corporate network? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#redirect-sites-from-microsoft-edge-to-ie-mode Did you use Enterprise Site list or the other option? BTW, corporate network administration is likely off topic here, as that's not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

> webpage.com:8000 / webpage.com:8001

According to what is mentioned in your question, these sites should belong to the same domain, and you should have added the IE mode site list in Edge settings rather than through group policy.. In this case, if you open another site page from IE mode site, it will also be in IE mode. This is by design. If you open an external public site (such as Bing, Google), you will find that it works in normal Edge mode.

So, in my opinion, this is browser behavior. What you can do is manually open a new Edge instance or tab and visit the site you need instead of navigating from the IE mode site.

When you use `Group Policy` to manage whether corporate sites are accessed in IE mode, it should not have such a problem. Only configured pages will work in IE mode. I did some simple testing locally and it works as configured by group policy. For more details, please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-sites-on-the-enterprise-site-list) that already mentioned by Lex Li.